# Add Pagination in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-pagination

I am trying to use `PageNumberPagination` in DRF anf for that I have changed the settings.py file like the following:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    # 'PAGE_SIZE':10
}
```

and views.py

from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

```
class GrnListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = GrnListSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, GRNViewPermission)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Grn.objects.all()
```

now when I try to access the data using the URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/grns/?page=1&page_size=10
```

It gives me all the data rather than returning 10 objects. It works fine when I uncomment the `PAGE_SIZE` but only returns 10 values per page, which is understandable as I have mentioned
`page_size=10` in my params but when I change it to 20 or 30 it still returns the same amount of data instead of 20 or 30 objects.

Comment: It looks like you missed the part where you configure a query parameter name that would be consider as page size. You need to create custom pagination class and inherit from `PageNumberPagination` https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination and then specify `page_size_query_param = 'page_size'` like it is done in example https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#modifying-the-pagination-style. The new class must be used in `'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS'`

Comment: this is actually an answer. thank you